# FoxPro Command to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, indexing, command, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I 'm running a FoxPro Command in Visual Studio 2017.
I want To execute the second command text pre-requisite To the first, And so on. Any help?

```
Dim a = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\temp;Extended Properties=dBase IV"

Using cn As New OleDbConnection(a)
    cn.Open()

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "use C:\temp\products"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cmd.CommandText = "INDEX ON productid TAG productid"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()

    cmd.CommandText = "INDEX ON prodname TAG prodname"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()

    cn.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: Write those commands as a single piece of code and use that as an argument to ExecScript().

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Visual FoxPro ExecScript() command and don't execute the the commands asynchronously.

```
Dim a = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\temp;Extended Properties=dBase IV"

Using cn As New OleDbConnection(a)
    cn.Open()

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "execscript(['use C:\temp\products excl'])"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cmd.CommandText = "execscript(['INDEX ON productid TAG productid'])"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cmd.CommandText = "execscript(['INDEX ON prodname TAG prodname'])"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cn.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: for safety, shouldn't they use the table exclusively before the index...

Comment: Thanks have amended,

Comment: You can use async. Write those lines as a single block of codes.